# Hide numbers with javascript, without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have the [following fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/WnLUu/3/).

When you click the Hide button the numbers 2, 3 and 1 are hidden. All works great using this Jquery code:

```
$( "#hide" ).click(function() {
   $('span').each(function(){
   if($(this).text().match(/^([1-9])$/))$(this).hide()
});
```

});

Now I want the same thing, but with using a good old javascript function instead of the jQuery solution given above. How to do this? [See my (not working) attempt here](http://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/WnLUu/4/).

Many thanks

Comment: wrap code in head .It works --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/WnLUu/5/

Comment: @TusharGupta There's still jQuery in that code. `$('span').each(function () {`

Comment: @VilleRouhiainen I know that.That's why i posted it as comment not as an answer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple vanilla JS version:

```
function hide() {
    var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span'), i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<spans.length; i++) {
        spans[i].style.display = (spans[i].innerText.match(/^[1-9]+$/) ? 'none' : '');
    }
}
```

Note: I've corrected your regex to match numbers with more than 1 digit in it.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WnLUu/6/

Comment: .innertText is not available on all browsers, if .innerText === undefined you should use .textContent instead.

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity, how would I make them visible again if I had another button called: Show? With Jquery you can simply use show.

Comment: With vanilla Js, you can just as easily do: `yourSpan.style.display = 'inline';`

Answer (score 0):

In plain javascript you could access the style attribute, so instead of $(this).hide() you could call

```
this.style.visibility = "hidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.

```
function buttonClicked(evt) {
    var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for (var i = 0, length = spans.length; i < length; ++i) {
        if (/^([1-9])$/.test(spans[i].innerHTML)) {
             spans[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
};


document.getElementById("hide").addEventListener("click", buttonClicked, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this (works on IE and other browsers, .innerText is IE specific):

```
function hide() {
    var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('SPAN');

    for (var i=0; i < spans.length; i++) {
        alert(spans[i].textContent);
        if (spans[i].textContent !== undefined && spans[i].textContent.match(/^[1-9]$/))
            spans[i].style.display = 'none';
        else if (spans[i].innerText !== undefined && spans[i].innerText.match(/^[1-9]$/)) // IE
            spans[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```